# How to get correct XPath result

Tags: objective-c, xpath

When I use XPath I use the following code:

```
NSArray *version = [doc nodesForXPath:@"/app/version[1]" error:nil];
```

And if I print the array I get this:

```
"GDataXMLElement 0x80d5030: {type:1 name:version xml:\"<version>0.6</version>\"}"
```

But how do I get the "0.6" out of the version? Am I doing this wrong with the array?

**EDIT:**

I found the solution:

```
for (GDataXMLElement *version in versions) {

    GDataXMLElement *versxml = (GDataXMLElement *) [versions objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", versxml.stringValue);

}
```

Comment: The XPath to get the data will be `data(/app/version[1])`, I can't help you with Objective C, though.

Comment: THanks, this gives the same result however